# javascript array find same values and its count from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want to find the duplicate values from array and its occurrences:-

```
const names = ['John', 'Paul',, 'Paul', 'Paul' 'George', 'John'];
```

it should print:-

```
john - 2
Paul - 3
George - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use `reduce`. Create object which has keys as `name` and it's occurrence (count) as a value.

```js
 const names = ['John', 'Paul', 'Paul', 'Paul', 'George', 'John'];

 const output = names.reduce((accu, name) => {
    accu[name] = (accu[name] || 0) + 1;
    return accu;
 }, {});

 console.log(output);
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for..can you please add short explanation?

Comment: @Yogi - See Edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using map and filter

```js
var a= ['John', 'Paul', 'Paul', 'Paul' ,'George', 'John'];
var obj={};
a.map(e=>{
obj[e]=a.filter(x=>x==e).length;
})
console.log(obj)
```